# Почему возможна регистрация пользователей с одинаковым логином?

Tags: php, регистрация

Есть регистрация, он заносит в базу всё нормально но проверки не срабатывают
Вот в чём дело.
Я в 1 раз зарегистрировался под логином `admin` захожу ещё раз на регистрацию и могу опять зарегистрироваться под логином `admin`.
И ещё в поле почта я могу ввести что хочу а желательно в формате `mail@site.ru`
Он заносит в базу 2 user с одинаковым логином.
Вот код:

```
include('connectdb.php');

if (($_POST['login']!='') || 
    ($_POST['pass1']!='') || 
    ($_POST['pass2']!='') || 
    ($_POST['email']!='')) {
    $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

    if (strcmp($pass1, $pass2) == 0) {
      $login = $_POST['login'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];

      $sql='SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='.$login;
      if (!($res=mysql_query($sql)) || (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0)) {
     $sql = 'INSERT INTO users(login, pass, email) 
        VALUES("'.$login.'", "'.$pass1.'", "'.$email.'")';
     if(mysql_query($sql)) {// выполняем скрипт
       echo 'Пользователь '.$_POST['login'].' успешно зарегистрирован! <a href="/index.php">Форма для входа.';
     } else {
       echo 'При регистрации произошла ошибка, <a href="/register.php">повторите попытку</a>.';
     }
   } else echo 'Пользователь с таким логином уже зарегистрирован!';
    } else echo 'Введенные пароли не совпадают, <a href="/register.php">повторите попытку</a>.';
} else {
```

Comment: чего бы уникальный индекс кроме всего прочего не сделать на поле login или email ? (зачем вам и логин и email ? )

Answer (score 2):

С дублированием проблема в этой строке

```
if (!($res=mysql_query($sql)) || (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0)
```

Достаточно проверки на количество полей.

Также проверяйте входящие данные (login password). Нельзя полученные данные от пользователя вставлять в SQL запрос.

```
function FormValid($data,$type){
        switch($type){
            case 'login':
                $edit = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/u", "", $data);
                break;  
            case 'password':
                $edit = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-_.,]/", "", $data);
            break;
        }
        if($data != $edit){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return $data;
        };
    }
```

По поводу проверки почты читайте доки по preg_match и регулярным выражениям.

Answer (score 1):

я б как минимум так сделал :)

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login'";
```

во вторых, ябы сначала почитал примеры, вот [первый попавшийся](http://freehabr.ru/blog/programming/3305.html)

зыж я НЕ говорю, что нужно делать именно так, однако там показан более-менее правильный синтаксис составления  запросов в склю....

Comment: Спасибо а проверку на mail можете подсказать ?! и ещё вот вопрос, ошибка открывается как бы в новом окне а можно что бы ошибки выше форму показывались

Comment: ну эт уже перебор :) Есть отличный сайт http://google.ru/ и там шикарнейше гуглится проверка email :)  

все в ваших руках, куда выведите -- там и будет показываться.

Comment: Вы говорите вот этот по лучше скрипт ?!
http://freehabr.ru/blog/programming/3305.html

Comment: Вы с тем кодом помочь можете что бы была проверка что бы вводили не просто а именно mail@site.ru

Comment: я б сейчас про этом не думал, чтобы валидировать прямо при вводе вам нужно смотреть в сторону javascript. Но судя по коду -- еще рано.